# cakephp find('all') statement returns double entry

Tags: cakephp

I am working with a site using cakephp 1.3. Last month i have changed hosting service of the site. After that i am having a issue.

ie. I have bookings table in my DB. When i am using find() statement, bookings table returns double entry. I could not find why this is happening.

For example, I got the vehicle data of the particular place returns the below,

when i use 'recursive'=>2 in find('all') statement ,I got the following

---

**

```
Parking Location : Chennai Citi Centre 2W
Booking Date : 02/04/2013
Booking ID  Transaction Type    Vehicle No  Check In Date       Check Out Date
187994      Normal          7099        02/04/2013 18:31    02/04/2013 22:03
187994      Normal          7099        02/04/2013 18:31    02/04/2013 22:03
```

**

But when i use 'recursive'=>-1 in find('all') statement,I got the following

```
**

Parking Location :
Booking Date : 02/04/2013
Booking ID  Transaction Type    Vehicle No  Check In Date       Check Out Date
187994      Normal          7099        02/04/2013 18:31    02/04/2013 22:03
```

**

Here parking location is not coming. Its in providers table.

Please anyone help me to fix this

Answer (score 0):

Normally I wouldn't recommend using anything other than `recursive=>-1`, and just use containable behavior when appropriate.
I can't really tell you why the first approach returns double entries without knowing the models associations, or having the exact find query you're using (are you doing a find() with the Bookings or the Parking or what else :S ?), but try and use containable and see if it works.

Something like... (I'm just going to assume how your models are called and how you're using find())

```
$this->Booking->find('all', array('conditions'=> array() ,//some conditions here
                                  'recursive' => -1,
                                  'contain' => array('Parking'));
```

After that, do a dump of the returned array to see if the output fits your needs. For more of containable behavior [check here](http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/The-Manual/Core-Behaviors/Containable.html).